# How do you show a slide number in Hindi (Arabian)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010, page-numbers, farsi

In Powerpoint 2010, how do you show the slide number in Hindi (Arabian or Farsi)?

Now, with choosing `Insert > Slide Number` create a Latin slide number!

Answer (score -1):

This is somewhat onerous if you have a large presentation, but will work in a pinch:

1. Create a new section (Home tab > Section > Add Section)
2. Go to Insert > Header & Footer
3. Click the Footer checkbox and type the page number in the character set you want
4. Repeat this for each slide

Again, this will work, but requires you to manually number each slide and also to make sure the page numbers are in order. If you rearrange your slides and don't update these numbers, you will see things like 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 7.

Comment: Oh Sorry,
This is a very basic way. And anyone know this way. I am looking for the main way that the number automaticaly create.